# how to create httpprovider for another server

Tags: wowza

i tried to create httpprovider in eclipe and when run in wowza media server it does not load properly it returns only wowza server version.
code of eclipse is here

```
package com.domain.appname;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.wowza.wms.vhost.IVHost;
import com.wowza.wms.http.HTTProvider2Base;
import com.wowza.wms.http.IHTTPRequest;
import com.wowza.wms.http.IHTTPResponse;

public class CreateApp extends HTTProvider2Base {

    public void onHTTPRequest(IVHost inVhost, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp){

        String ret = req.getQueryString();

        resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        byte[] outBytes = ret.toString().getBytes();
        try {
            out.write(outBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and also set vhost file as

```
<HTTPProvider>
<BaseClass>com.domain.appname.CreateApp</BaseClass>
<RequestFilters>CreateProducerApp*</RequestFilters>
<AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
</HTTPProvider>
```

Please help

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing your complete vhost.xml, my guess would be that you put your new HTTPProvider last in the list of HTTPProviders.

When the server processes http requests it starts at the first one and tries each one.  The RequestFilter for the provider that returns the server info is "*" which means no providers after this one will get called.  This is usually the last one.  Do make sure yours is before this one.

Answer (score 1):

Please put your HTTPProvider entry in vHosts file before following block:

```xml
<HTTPProvider>              
  <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerVersion</BaseClass>
  <RequestFilters>*</RequestFilters>
  <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
</HTTPProvider>
```

Otherwise all of your request will give Wowza version details.

So, your final vhost file's end should look like:

```xml
<HTTPProvider>
  <BaseClass>com.domain.appname.CreateApp</BaseClass>
  <RequestFilters>CreateProducerApp*</RequestFilters>
  <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
</HTTPProvider>
<HTTPProvider>              
  <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerVersion</BaseClass>
  <RequestFilters>*</RequestFilters>                            
  <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
</HTTPProvider>
```